# How to manipulate lists in Python selenium?

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have some entries that are to be made in a web portal.
The entries that are to be made are in excel file. I have imported those in python and converted them to lists so that I can access them to pick up individual entry.

Will try to explain code approach here

find first element and use send keys to first element of the list
same for next two fields and then save the entry.
(ignore syntax in below)

```
driver.find_element_by_name("01st elementname").send_keys(list1[0])
driver.find_element_by_name("02nd elementname").send_keys(list2[0])
driver.find_element_by_name("03rd elementname").send_keys(list3[0])
```

Till this portion is done.

Next I have to move to second and make entry with next index

```
driver.find_element_by_name("01st elementname").send_keys(list1[1])

driver.find_element_by_name("02nd elementname").send_keys(list2[1])

driver.find_element_by_name("03rd elementname").send_keys(list3[1])
```

move to next.

How can I do this ? Not being able to figure out for loop for this.
I hope I explained this well. Could be very simple but I am not from programming background so need some help.

Comment: How about using _Pandas_?

Comment: @DebanjanB Yes using pandas to read excel. Struggling to put list in a loop where the index 0 entry will keep changing till the time all browser entries are done. So, all entries from first row are done from excel so that row get deleted and python should start picking the entries from second row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean how to loop over the list like this?

```
 for i in range(len(list1)): 
    driver.find_element_by_name("01st elementname").send_keys(list1[i]) 
    driver.find_element_by_name("02nd elementname").send_keys(list2[i]) 
    driver.find_element_by_name("03rd elementname").send_keys(list3[i])
```

//submit click() if required

See also https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: @Kiran please accept the answer if it works, than other people know the question is answered and can look for other people to help :-)